# How to count items with some property

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

Using https://query.wikidata.org  I need to count the number of `Q*` items of Wikidata that have a statement with P402. Something like

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {?item wdt:P402.}
```

but, of course, it is an invalid query.

Comment: One minor comment to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165361/7879193): try `p:P402` instead of `wdt:P402`. As of 2018-07-04, the difference between two results is caused by [wd:Q696334](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q696334).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause does not specify a valid basic triple pattern: an RDF triple consists of three items (subject, predicate, and object), where your pattern only contains two. Not knowing the Wikidata vocabulary too well, I'll assume that `wdt:P402` is the predicate you're interested in. If that is case, your pattern is missing a variable or placeholder for the object of the triple pattern.

To fix this, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {?item wdt:P402 ?object.}
```

Or (since you're not really interested in the value of the object), use a blank node instead:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {?item wdt:P402 [].}
```

Finally, if you want to make sure that items which have more than one value for this property do not get counted more than once, you also need to add a `DISTINCT` clause to your query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE {?item wdt:P402 [].}
```

Comment: Yes (!),  and the DISTINCT  is perfect, as real life solution.